# Python, Django and flatpage

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use Django and to add a flatpage.

ValueError at /admin/flatpages/flatpage/add/

Cannot use None as a query value

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/flatpages/flatpage/add/
Django Version:     1.4.2
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:
```

Cannot use None as a query value

```
Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in add_filter, line 1095
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\ivo\\Desktop\\eclipse-jee-indigo\\workspace\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\ivo\\Desktop\\eclipse-jee-indigo\\workspace\\blog',
...
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

How to get rid of it?

Thank you

Comment: Stacktrace ? Exception message ?

Comment: Have to give all my code containing about 30 files? I try from a course videos in website http://www.udemy.com/full-django-tutorial/ .

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug in Django 1.4. You get the error if you attempt to save a flatpage without choosing a value for `sites`

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18234

It has been fixed for the upcoming Django 1.5. For Django 1.4, you can avoid the problem by specifying a site for your flatpage.

Comment: In where python file to choose value of sites?

Comment: You don't need to change any python files. On the add flatpage web page, you have to select a value for sites.